# Angular js: How to pic 2 data at a time with "ng-repeat"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I want to achieve something like this with "angularJS".

```
var myData = [ "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", ... ];

var cDom = "";

for(var i=1;i<totalLength;i++) 
{
    cDom = cDom + "<div>";

    cDom = cDom + "<span>"+myData[i]+"</span>";

    i = i+1;

    cDom = cDom + "<span>"+myData[i]+"</span>"

    cDom = cDom + "</div>";
}
```

ouput DOM should be:

```
<div>
    <span>Data1</span>
    <span>Data2</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Data3</span>
    <span>Data4</span>
</div>

...
```

I have achieved this by creating separate service block and all(creating a new json). But i need some way within a template to handle this..

Could it be possible. Beginner in AngularJS. Please suggest few methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='data in myData'>
  <span ng-if='$index % 2 == 0'>{{data}}</span>
  <span ng-if='$index % 2 == 0 && ($index+1)<myData.length'>{{myData[$index+1]}}</span>
</div>
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/aOI211jDIpQ2YnHk9Djk?p=preview

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just for interest, i want something like this: for(var i=1;i<totalLength;i++){i++;}

Comment: I totally understand you want to increase the index in the loop, but beyond just using $index+1 what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i agreed with your solution. But let me know if it is possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want on the actual view.  You can however preprocess your data before it is on the view (or a filter) but the actual solution depends on what  you are trying to actually achieve.

Comment: hi if i am not wrong, with this solution for every odd index a empty div is created(<div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div><div></div><div><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>). I want to avoid this.

Comment: i can achieve, by checking $index%2 == 0 before this <div></div>, but will facing some ui library issues ?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not worry about the dom structure, you can group two adjacent elements using `$even` and `$odd` while iterating with `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData">
    <span ng-if="$even">{{data}}</span>
    <span ng-if="$odd">{{data}}<hr></span>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3C78/)**

Comment: I always forget about those `$even` and `$odd` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

you can seperate your data with ng-repeat and ng-if,
here is an example

```
<table><tbody class="dates">
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-if="$index < 3">
                            <span>
                                {{data}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-if="$index > 2">
                           <span>
                                {{data}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
```